# How to resolve character breakage that occurs in file/folder name during zip/unzip action in java?

Tags: java, windows, encoding, character-encoding, unzip

I am using the following code snippet to unzip a file.

```
public void zipFiles(String zipFile){

     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
     String charset = "UTF-8";

     try{

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
        zos.setEncoding(charset);

        System.out.println("Output to Zip : " + zipFile);

        for(String file : this.fileList){

            System.out.println("File Added : " + file);
            ZipEntry ze= new ZipEntry(file);
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);

            FileInputStream in =
                       new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FOLDER + File.separator + file);

            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            in.close();
        }

        zos.closeEntry();
        //remember close it
        zos.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(IOException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

When my file/folder name is in English this works fine. But for others like Russian characters are not supported during this. ie; the file name or folder name has breakage while unzipping it.

This works fine with mac os but not as expected in windows and linux. Any help in this is much appreciated.

Comment: Sry that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Cp437 - charset is set for special characters. But mine is Russian characters.. Which still doesn't appear to be fixed..